# TextView is not visible inside Linear (vertical) layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my XML code.
I have an outer vertical linear layout.
Inside this there is a horizontal linear layout that contains two TextViews.
Below the horizontal layout is another TextView. But this is not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.praveenmuthukumarana.coursework1_quizapp.GameActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the output

[image]

I'm expecting something like this.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Set height of second linearlayout to wrap_content. Or both linearlayout .

Comment: Thats because of height=match_parent I think,change it to wrap_content.It will work after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the height of the inner LinearLayout as "wrap content", you have set it as "match_parent"

wrap_content -> wrap its content, take only the size needed by the view or its inner views and wrap it.

match_parent -> matches to the size of its parent, take all the space of its parent container.

Here your inner LinearLayout has taken all the space of its parent, leaving none for the other view to draw

Answer (score 1):

Make the height of the second linerar layout wrap content.
Your linear layout view is overlapped on the text view that why text view is not visible

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make height of horizontal `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` as in

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // only change is here
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```